# Почему во время beep программа зависает?

Tags: c#, winapi, консоль

Почему когда я делаю в программе `Console.Beep(1000, 35000);`, то она зависает и настолько зависает, что даже не появляется сообщение "Программа не отвечает"?

---

**UPD** :

Почему у меня всё равно она подвисает не смотря на то что я вывел beep в асинхронный поток?

```
    static async Task beeping()
    {
        Console.Beep(1000, 1000);
    }

    private void refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Content = "Последнее обновление было "+ lastref++.ToString() + " сек. назад";
        if (beep == true)
        {
            var task = beeping();
            task.Wait();
        }
    }
```

**UPD** :

Попробовал по другому, тоже не помогает

```
static void beeping()
{
    Console.Beep(1000, 1000);
}

private void refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Content = "Последнее обновление было "+ lastref++.ToString() + " сек. назад";
    if (beep == true)
    {
        SomeDelegate sd = beeping;
        IAsyncResult asyncRes = sd.BeginInvoke(null,null);
        sd.EndInvoke(asyncRes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Content = "Последнее обновление было "+ lastref++.ToString() + " сек. назад";
    if (beep == true)Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.Beep(1000, 1000));
}
```

Comment: О, вот так хорошо пошло ) Спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Потому что `Console.Beep` - это синхронная функция, она блокирует выполнение программы на определенное время. Если хотите, чтобы не блокировалось, вызывайте ее в отдельном потоке.

> даже не появляется сообщение "Программа не отвечает"?

Потому что это сообщение актуально для программ, у которых есть оконный интерфейс и цикл сообщений. То есть, оно появляется, когда программа перестает обрабатывать сообщения от системы. А у консольных программ нет цикла сообщений.

Comment: Вот я всё правильно говорю, а если её кинуть в асинхронный поток, поможет?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, выполняйте ваш `Beep` в отдельном потоке, если хотите делать ещё что-то в то же самое время.

Comment: @aleks.andr теперь осталось научиться работать с асинхронными потоками :)

Comment: @aleks.andr посмотрите пожалуйста почему поток не помогает, тему обновил.

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy вы принудительно вызываете .Wait(), т.е. ждать окончания работы, вот он и висит

Comment: @Etki я убрал wait, но он всё равно ждёт (

Comment: @Etki ну вот я ещё попробовал по другому, ни как не хочет

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4fe3hdb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1):

> Параметры
>
> frequency
>
> ```
> Частота сигнала в диапазоне от 37 до 32767 Гц.
> ```
>
> duration
>
> ```
> Длительность сигнала в миллисекундах.
> ```

Могу предположить, что вам просто не слышно ваш звуковой сигнал длительностью 35 (!) секунд из-за отсутствия (или отключения) встроенного динамика?

Comment: Нет, всё пищит как надо, но у меня программа дальше beep не идёт, точнее пока она не отпищит 35 секунд программа делать не чего не хочет. Может пищалку вывести в асинхронный поток?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, само собой в том же потоке, где вызов `Beep`, программа ничего делать и не будет. Вызов `Beep` блокирует поток выполнения до своего завершения.